# Log to console only when run from cli command

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, command-line-interface

I'm currently developing a node js cli tool to do some random stuff for work.
Up until this point, my whole app was designed as a cli without any intention to use its functionality somewhere else.

Now some of my collegues like to work with a ui instead of a cli so I decited to build a vue web app around it. SO far so good.

Now my problem: I plastered all of my functions with console.logs and packages like cliui, chalk, inquirer, etc. This obviously makes no sense when used as a module in a vue app.

**My question is: How do I log output from individual functions only when used via cli?**

One idea I have is to set some kind of falgg in my command function so the process knows I'm in a terminal and check for every console.log if that flag is set. But that seems to be a lot of work and I wonder if there is a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly suggest to use some logging library, like for instance [winston](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston). There you can define multiple so called transports, which are responsible for writing the logs in the respective specified location (for instance a file, a database or just the console). Then do all your logging only through this library.

So you will have a single point in the very beginning of your app, where you can define whether to activate a transport to the console or not ...

Comment: Thank you, the concept of transports is what I was missing. Thats why I marked this as the solution.

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be to use something like Winston as your logger. This could be a very simple and quick 'search and replace' for replacing 'console' with 'winston'. When you start the application, set the log level and you're set

```
const winston = require('winston');
winston.level = 'debug';
winston.log('debug', 'default logger being used');
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not versed in NodeJS that well, but what I can suggest is "guard clauses" in each method that has CLI outputs and some sort of `isCLI` boolean flag as an optional parameter to manipulate that clause.

That could be ugly, so another approach would be to separate out the CLI outputs and have a `--verbose` flag or the likes for your CLI for when you want to see said outputs